# why a method on vue child component get called twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a todo app that I am working on which I divided it into two component one for form and the other for the todo list. in todo list I have a Method that delete the todo but it delete two todo instead of one I tried to console log the component that I click on and found that it get logged twice. I tried prevent method on click solution i found it here in stackoverflow but it didn't work.

```
<template>
  <div class="todo" v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="index">
    <div class="todo-text">{{ todo.text }}</div>
    <div class="IconDiv">
      <fa @click.prevent="deleteTodo(index)" class="icon" icon="trash-alt" />
      <fa @click="completeTodo(index)" class="icon" icon="edit" />
      <fa class="icon" icon="check-square" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoList",
  emits: ["removeTodo", "completEmit"],

  props: {
    msg: String,
    todos: Array,
    val: String
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    deleteTodo(index) {
      return console.log(this.todos[index].text);
    }

  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: did you try out `@click.stop="deleteTodo(index)"`?

Comment: do you have a reproducible example to post?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes I did>

Comment: @zim I don't know how to explain it further cli project make it harder to explain the code.

Comment: What does the prop todos look like? It says it's an Object and you're looping through it. Is that correct?

Comment: yes it its an object but I changed it to Array because it is in the first place but nothing changed.